# Telerik Mvc Grid and sub-property like Contact.Name when the contact is null

Tags: nullreferenceexception, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

i use `telerik` grid in an `mvc` project.
I have a 'complex' model that i don't want change and have a structure like this:

```
task
task.Contact
task.Contact.FirstName
```

in telerik grid i want to show all the task with the name of the Contact...but the contact CAN be null: in this case telerik return (rightly) an error for `nullreferenceException`, how can avoid this and display an empty value in the column?

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Contact.FullName).Title("Contact").Width(250);
```

tnx at all

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by specifying the Template of the bound column:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Contact.FullName)
       .Template(p => 
       {
          %>
             <%= (p.Contact != null ? p.Contact.FullName : "") %>
          <%
       }
       .Title("Contact")
       .Width(250);
```

Or you can use ClientTemplate:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Contact.FullName)
       .ClientTemplate("<#= Contact? Contact.FullName : '' #>");
```

Comment: You can use ClientTemplate too. I will modify my reply.